# Why is the audio executed after the prompt?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, audio, prompt, single-threaded

```
function myTimer() {
    randint= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)+1;
    randstimuli=gorilla.stimuliURL(dict[randint]);
    var audio = new Audio(randstimuli);
    audio.play();
    var start=Date.now();
    var ans=prompt("was the last number the same as the one two steps ago");
    console.log(Date.now()-start);
}
```

I have this function in which I play a sound and ask the user via the prompt a question. When I run the function sound is played immediately after answering the prompt, even though the audio precedes the prompt in the code. Due to the single-threaded nature of Javascript I assume the audio is run asynchronously, due to an assumption of the audio length.

My audio are very short, they contain just one word. I want them to be finished before the prompt opens.

Comment: Because the prompt blocks all the execution on the page called it. That is said to be a modal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the `onended` event of the `audio` and perform the action in the callback.

Example:

```
function myTimer() {
   randint = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
   randstimuli = gorilla.stimuliURL(dict[randint]);
   var audio = new Audio(randstimuli);
   audio.play();
   audio.onended = function () {
      var start = Date.now();
      var ans = prompt("was the last number the same as the one two steps ago");
      console.log(Date.now() - start);
   }

}
```